# i am trying to load a json file and get an error

Tags: python, json

jdata gives an error I am just not sure why it wont load. this is the output.
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
url = 'http://hahnix.com/2021/02/16/have-a-lot-of-older-trees-2-tips-to-keep-them-healthy/'

response = requests.get(url)
    
print(response.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html')
    
print(soup.title.text)
    
post = soup.find("script", {"type":"application/ld+json"}).text
    
    try:
        with open('post_data.json','a',encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            outfile.write(post)
            outfile.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        outfile.close()

jdata = json.loads('post_data.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to load from a file, then you should use the `load` function as opposed to the `loads` function.

```
jdata = None
with open('post_data.json') as json_file:
    jdata = json.load(json_file)
```

Comment: I think I found the problem here. I still get an error but i think its an encoding issue. I'm not sure I know how to handle this one.                                                             
JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 29 column 43 (char 554)                  
          '"datePublished": "2021-02-16 15:13:10 \x2b0000",'

Comment: It's not valid JSON.

Comment: i realized that, I'm stil not sure why thought

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that using .text caused the problem. if i use .contents on the BeautifulSoup object the post writes to a json file but still produces an error.
i know it has to do with an invalid escape character.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
url = 'http://hahnix.com/2021/02/16/have-a-lot-of-older-trees-2-tips-to-keep-them-healthy/'

response = requests.get(url)
    
print(response.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html')
    
print(soup.title.text)
    
post = soup.find("script", {"type":"application/ld+json"}).contents
    
with open('post_data.json','a',encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    outfile.write(post)
    outfile.close()

jdata = None
with open('post_data.json') as json_file:
    jdata = json.load(json_file)
```